# sending and receiving objects in mqtt by Serialization and deserialization results in classnotfound exception

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, classnotfoundexception, mqtt

I am using mqtt to send and receive messages between client and server. The messages are sent in the form of bytes. I need to send a class object in the mqtt messages.

I tried serializing the object into bytes as follows

```
deviceloc d=new deviceloc();
d.id=mqttClientId;
d.add=strAddress;
d.lat=loc.getLatitude();
d.lon=loc.getLongitude();
ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream o=new ObjectOutputStream(b);
o.writeObject(d);
o.close();
byte bytes[]=b.toByteArray();
```

Here deviceloc is a class in package `com.example.cv_client_android`

I am sending message as below

```
mqttClient.publish("admin/location",bytes,MQTT_QUALITY_OF_SERVICE,MQTT_RETAINED_PUBLISH);
```

On the server side, i receive the message and deserialize that as below

```
public void publishArrived(String topic, byte[] payloadbytes, int qos, boolean retained)
        throws Exception {
ByteArrayInputStream b1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(payloadbytes);
        ObjectInputStream o1 = new ObjectInputStream(b1);
        deviceloc obj1=(deviceloc)o1.readObject();
        System.out.println(obj1.id);
        System.out.println(obj1.add);
        System.out.println(obj1.lat);
        System.out.println(obj1.lon);
}
```

Here the class deviceloc is there in package name pack.

Message successfully sent on client side. T get the following error in server side,

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.cv_client_android.deviceloc
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at pack.Controller.publishArrived(Controller.java:450)
    at com.ibm.mqtt.MqttClient.publishArrived(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.mqtt.MqttBaseClient.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.mqtt.MqttPublish.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.mqtt.Mqtt.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.mqtt.MqttBaseClient.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The class of a deserialized object must be available on the CLASSPATH of the receiver.

Comment: class of a deserialized object is com.example.cv_client_android.deviceloc or pack.deviceloc? First one is available in client side, latter in server side. How can i bring client side class on server side. Please provide a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Can i use google JSON for this purpose. What are the pros and cons. Please help me with this, Thank you

Comment: The class that is missing is the class that is named in the exception. It is sounding like you have the same class in two packages. You can't do that, at least not while expecting them to be interchangeable. They aren't.

Comment: @EJP- Both the packages are in different machines.

Comment: I don't know what that means, but if you serialize a.b.c.D you must have *that class* available at the target. Another class with the same name in a different package will not do.